# FullCalendar popover get hidden under div

Tags: css, fullcalendar

When I have many events in my calendar. My popover goes under div and a part of him not showing is hidden. I tried set z-index and change position but still not working.

[image: popover get hidden under div]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried z-index positioning on both the covered element and the div that covers it, for examble

```
.covered-element { z-index:+5(or even + 99)}
```

and

```
.div-that-covers { z-index:+1 }
```